# How to document database usage with PHPdoc?

Tags: php, database, documentation-generation, phpdoc

Now I am wondering if others document database usage in function headers ... for instance, a fn() might read or write a database (or table thereof), or create, modify or drop a database or table. (side question: should a fn() which changes the database with "USE xxx" 'remember' the current database on entry and USE it again before exit?)

It seems to me that this sort of thing **should** be documented, but how best to do so? `@uses`, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use @link and a list, along with list of helpers:

```
/**
 * Some comments here.
 *
 * Helper functions:
 * * {@link someHelper}
 * * {@link theOtherHelper}
 *
 * Reads tables:
 * * {@link Table1}
 * * {@link Table2}
 *
 * Reads/Writes tables:
 * * {@link Table3}
 * * {@link Table4}
 */
```

Then you make some topic pages for those tables, with nothing but a short description, "Holds parameters for business process X."